# How to get from cgo to exe

Tags: c, go

From a basic test program. . .

```
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
static void test() {
        printf("hello world");
}
*/
import "C"

func main() {
        C.test();
}
```

I do "cgo hello_cgo.go" and get:

```
_cgo_.o
_cgo_defun.c
_cgo_gotypes.go 
hello_cgo.cgo1.go 
hello_cgo.cgo2.c
```

How do I go about compiling from here to an exe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the go makefiles. Create a makefile like

```
# Makefile
CGOFILES=test.go
TARG=test

include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.$(GOARCH)
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.pkg
```

Running make will then produce the file `_obj/test.a`, which you'll have to link with `6l` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Update for go1:

```
$ cat foo.go
package main

// #include <stdio.h>
// static void test() { printf("Hello, world\n"); }
import "C"

func main() {
    C.test()
}
$ go build foo.go
$  ./foo
Hello, world
```